# Parse plain text from rtf text in ruby

Tags: ruby, rtf

I have an rtf text shown like below,

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
This line is the default color\line
\cf2
\tab This line is red and has a tab before it\line
\cf1
\page This line is the default color and the first line on page 2
}
```

I want to parse plain text from rtf text. Is there any plugins or any other solutions available in ruby, to parse plain text from rtf text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this [Ruby-rtf Gem](https://github.com/dj2/Ruby-RTF)

```
require 'ruby-rtf'

data = File.read('./rich.rtf')
parser = RubyRTF::Parser.new
parsed_text = parser.parse(data).sections.map do |val|
  val[:text]
end.join(' ')
```